# Mvc.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationFilter - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'unitOfWork')

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I upgraded abp framework to 6.3.1 and also upgraded .Net framework version. After upgrade, getting below exception -

> Mvc.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationFilter -
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'unitOfWork')

Any pointers on how to fix this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: @aaron, do you know how to fix this or any pointers?

Comment: Share a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: This happens if page remains idle for sometime. Refreshing page resolves this issue.